# Django render_to_string not working (Django 1.4)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to return a result set from an ajax search using Django. I'd like this result set to be displayed in a template and then i'd like the template to returned back after a successful django response.

```
    context ={}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_text = request.POST.get('search')
        monitors = RaspPiMonitor.objects.filter(
                     mac_address__icontains=search_text)
        context={
            'monitors':monitors,
        }

        html = render_to_string('realtime_reports/search_results.html', context)
        return HttpResponse(html)

    return render(request,'realtime_reports/monitors.html',context)
```

Comment: And what happens? And why are you using Django 1.4, which is eight versions old and has not been supported in years?

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced

```
html = render_to_string('realtime_reports/search_results.html', context)
```

With

```
render(request, 'realtime_reports/search_results.html', context)
```